# Postgresql -es Date pero la expresion es character varying- error insertando?

Tags: java, postgresql, prepared-statements

Quiero insertar desde java en postgresql.
Al traer (y castear) una `java.util.Date` a `java.sql.Date`, funciona bien, pero a la hora de insertar me marca esto:

> ERROR: la columna «fechab1» es de tipo date pero la expresión es de
>   tipo character varying   Hint: Necesitará reescribir la expresión o
>   aplicarle una conversión de tipo.

Sin embargo, y como dije, ya había aplicado la conversión de tipo de datos. 
¿Qué podría tener mal?
dejo un ejemplo de como tengo mis conversiones:

---

### Codigo con PreparedStatament

```
ps=con.prepareStatament("insert into tabla (fecha1, fecha2) values (?,?)");

ps.setDate(1,castFechas(dts.getFecha1().getTime()));

ps.setDate(2,castFechas(dts.getFecha2().getTime()));

rs=ps.executeUpdate();

//dts.getFecha1() es un Java.util.Calendar
```

---

### Conversor:

```
private Date castFechas(java.util.Date fecha) {

    String fechastr=sf.format(fecha.getTime());

    System.out.println("fechastr: "+fechastr);

    java.util.Date fechaJU=null;

    java.sql.Date fechasql=null;

    try {

        fechaJU=sf.parse(fechastr);

        fechasql= new java.sql.Date(fechaJU.getTime());

    } catch (ParseException e) {

        System.out.println("error: "+e.getMessage());

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return fechasql;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola una vez que tengas el formato deseado de tu fecha lo debes asignar así en el ps.

ps.setDate(1,java.sql.Date.valueOf(castFechas(dts.getFecha1().getTime()))); en tu caso.

te facilito un método de ejemplo,en donde se realiza una búsqueda por fecha_registro y si existen resultados lo carga en una tabla.

```
public void FiltrarVenta(){

dtm.setRowCount(0);
Date hoy= Reportepordia.hoy.getDate();
SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-d");
String fechaSelec = formato.format(hoy);

Sql="SELECT f.n_factura_v, f.fecha_registro,\n" +
"d.catidad,d.preciou,d.total,\n" +
"p.nombre\n" +
"  FROM factura_venta f\n" +
"  inner join detalle_venta as d on d.n_factura_v=f.n_factura_v\n" +
"  inner join producto as p on p.id_producto=d.id_producto\n" +
"  where estado_factura and fecha_registro=?";
  boolean bandera=false;
    try {
        pst=ConexionDB.getDBcon().prepareStatement(Sql);
        pst.setDate(1,java.sql.Date.valueOf(fechaSelec));
        rst=pst.executeQuery();
        while (rst.next()) {                
        dtm.addRow(new Object[]{
         rst.getInt("n_factura_v"),rst.getString("nombre"),rst.getInt("preciou"),rst.getInt("catidad"),rst.getInt("total")
                ,rst.getDate("fecha_registro")
        });
       bandera=true;
        }
         SumarTotalVenta(fechaSelec);

    if(bandera==false){   
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No Existen Registros","Atencion",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);               
}

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR AL RECUPERAR " +e.getMessage());

    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias, ya habia encontrado que era el problema jaja, era un dato que estaba mal, pero igual se aagradece